# Using babel and lingua in pyramid

Tags: python, localization, internationalization, pyramid, python-babel

I've problems with babel and lingua. I want babel/lingua to scan my source folder for specific strings for creating the pot-catalog.

This is my setup.py

```
...

requires = [
    ...
    'Babel',
    'lingua',
    ]

extractors = { 'dbas': [
    ('**.py', 'python', None ),
    ('**.pt', 'chameleon', None ),
    ('static/**', 'ignore', None),
    ]}

setup(name='DBAS',
    ...
    message_extractors=extractors,
    ...
    )
```

And my setup.cfg

```
[compile_catalog]
directory = dbas/locale
domain = mydbas
statistics = true

[extract_messages]
copyright_holder = Acme Inc.
output_file = dbas/locale/mydbas.pot
charset = UTF-8

[init_catalog]
domain = mydbas
input_file = dbas/locale/mydbas.pot
output_dir = dbas/locale

[update_catalog]
domain = mydbas
input_file = dbas/locale/mydbas.pot
output_dir = dbas/locale
previous = true
```

In my **init**.py I have something like this:

```
config.add_translation_dirs('dbas:locale')
```

And for example my 404 template is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="${request.locale_name}"
            metal:use-macro="load: basetemplate.pt"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xml:lang="en"
            xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
            i18n:domain="dbas">

<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="${request.static_url('dbas:static/css/theme_center.css')}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="center">
        <div class="error">
            <h1><span class="font-semi-bold" i18n:translate="404">404 Error</span></h1>
            <p class="lead font-normal">The page &quot;<span class="font-semi-bold">${page_notfound_viewname}</span>&quot; for could not be found.</p>
            <br>
            <input class="button button-block btn-lg btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick="self.location.href='/'" value="Let's go home!" />
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<html>
```

Now I can run:

```
python3 setup.py develop
setup.py extract_messages
```

And I am receiving:

```
running extract_messages
extracting messages from dbas/__init__.py
extracting messages from dbas/helper.py
extracting messages from dbas/security.py
extracting messages from dbas/tests.py
extracting messages from dbas/views.py
extracting messages from dbas/database/__init__.py
extracting messages from dbas/database/initializedb.py
extracting messages from dbas/database/model.py
extracting messages from dbas/templates/404.pt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 60, in <module>
    """,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/babel/messages/frontend.py", line 305, in run
    for filename, lineno, message, comments, context in extracted:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/babel/messages/extract.py", line 163, in extract_from_dir
    strip_comment_tags):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/babel/messages/extract.py", line 190, in extract_from_file
    strip_comment_tags))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/babel/messages/extract.py", line 262, in extract
    raise ValueError('Unknown extraction method %r' % method)
ValueError: Unknown extraction method 'chameleon'
```

Does someone know, whats wrong?

Comment: Which version of pyramid, babel, lingua?

Comment: Babel 1.3, Lingua 3.10, Pyramid 1.5.6, everything installed with pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `message_extractors` configuration may be outdated for recent versions of babel and lingua. For debugging purposes you [could ask for lingua extractors](https://github.com/wichert/lingua#configuration). I actually do not know how to do this for babel.

```
$ bin/pot-create --list-extractors
chameleon         Chameleon templates (defaults to Python expressions)
python            Python sources
xml               Chameleon templates (defaults to Python expressions)
zcml              Zope Configuration Markup Language (ZCML)
zope              Zope templates (defaults to TALES expressions)
```

I recently followed [pyramid's narrative documentation for i18n/l10](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#installing-lingua-and-gettext). Extraction workflow seems to have changed. Using lingua >=3.0.9 and babel==1.3 I did not needed any setuptools integration configuration anymore like setup.cfg and defining `message_extractors` for a common case like mines & yours. Extraction of message strings from python & chameleon templates worked out-of-the-box. But pyramid documentation should be improved a bit.

A couple of days later [I notified the pyramid project about my observations on the topic](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/1645) and [suggested a small change to lingua i18n.sh script that helps finding fuzzy messages](https://github.com/wichert/lingua/issues/59). May be theses resources help you as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow and will write here :)

Comment: Sorry, there was much work todo. So I've tried the helper script and it worked out of the box. Now, just one little issue is left; I've to mark my strings which should be translated, but thats